# Как расширить функциональность метода?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Как расширить функциональность метода (функции). Например, есть некий класс (функция)

```
MyFunction = function() {
    this.myMethod = function() {
        //некие вычисления
    }
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при вызове функции `myMethod`, выполнялись команды которые внутри него, плюс еще несколько? Также необходимо чтобы все, что внутри функции (класса) `MyFunction` оставалось без изменения (т.е. не править код внутри `MyFunction`).

**UPD1**:
Если иными словами описать:
Есть порядка пятидесяти классов. В каждом из этих классов есть метод, который называется `initData`, который выполняет каждый свои операции. У всех этих классов есть один и тот же суперкласс (все пятьдесят классов расширяют функциональность одного класса (функции)). Мне понадобилось ко всем классам, к каждому методу, присобачить еще несколько одинаковых операций. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как?

**UPD2**:
Есть один класс

```
MySuperclass = function() {
    //некоторые методы
}
```

Есть ряд подклассов такого вида:

```
MySubclass1 = function() {
    //Некоторые методы, переопределяющие родительские
    //Плюс метод initData:
    this.initData = function() {
        //Содержание метода
        /*
           Основная проблема состоит в том, что я тут не указывал
           конструкцию вида
           MySubclass1.superclass.initData.apply(this, arguments);
        */
    }
}
//
```

Мне надо все методы `initData` в подклассах переопределить. Если все равно неясно, что надо сделать, спрашивайте.
**UPD3**:
Все подклассы наследуют свой суперкласс. то, как это происходит, я опустил из-за ненадобности.

Comment: Задачу нормально опишите, так как я ее понимаю сейчас - это невозможно и является дуристикой

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Функцию eval() не пробовали?

Comment: Не понимаю вашу идею.

Comment: т.е.

    function class1() {}
    class1.prototype.initData = function(){}

    function class2() {}
    class2.prototype.initData = function(){
       // тут надо вызвать родительский initData?..
    }

Если нет, то я не понимаю что именно вы хотите

Comment: что-то нереальное походу...

Comment: Если нужно то, что я написал выше - абсолютно реально

Comment: да я комент писал еще ничего небыло)

Comment: В родительском элементе нет функции `initData`. Она появляется только в подклассах. Еще. Можно менять родительский класс. Вообще, у меня есть только идея, чтобы как-то подменить этот метод своим, вызвав его после выполнения дополнительных. Например 
>>
initData: function() {
    //дополнительные методы
    superclass.initData();
}
>>
Ну как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ прост! Необходимо просто в конструктор суперкласса поместить переопределение метода:

```
this.constructor = function() {
    //console.log('constructor: function() {');
    var ld = this.initData;
    this.initData= function() {
        //Дополнительные методы
        ld.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    //MySuperclass.superclass.constructor.call(this, arguments);
}
```